# covariant derivative of Ricci operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am going through a calculation where we have in hand...
$\nabla_Y Du = -QY + \lambda Y,$ where $u$ and $\lambda$ are smooth real valued functions on a manifold $M$  and $Q$ is the Ricci operator. Then what is the value of $\nabla_{[X,Y]} Du$?

Comment: According to me $\nabla_{[X,Y]}Du=(XY-YX)Du$